# How do I pass back multiple select box selections to HTML form?

Tags: html, forms, perl, html-select

I am using Perl (and Dancer) with HTML to create a form. On my form I have some fields like so:

```
<input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywords" value="<% keywords | html %>"/>

<select multiple="multiple" id="sentences" name="sentences" size="3"/>
    <% IF list_of_sentences %>
         <% FOREACH sentence IN list_of_sentences %>
              <option value=<% sentence %>/>
         <% END %>
    <% END %>
</select>
```

These are, of course, inside their own divisions and there is more code around, but these are the essentials of what I've got.

These are in `main.tt` which is interacted with using `myApp.pm` and there are parameters which are passed back and forth (e.g. `keywords` and `list_of_sentences` here). The code is set up with two divs, one with the form and the other purely to show the output. When the form is submitted the output shows correctly, but the select field selections are not retained.

So therefore, what I want to do is make it so that the chosen selection(s) from the 'multiple select' are kept selected.

As an example, in my 'input' keywords field I have the value retained because it has been passed back from the `.pm` file using `param("keywords")` using `template 'main' ...`. This works with `value="<% keywords | html %>"` in the html code.
I have tried to do the same for the multiple select using `param("sentences")`, but this returns a blank field.

To hazard a guess at the problem it is because there is more than one option and maybe because I am getting the options from the `.pm` file to start with, but I haven't found the solution yet, so any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `selected="selected"` attribute on the option element.  I would suggest passing both the name of the sentence and flag stating if the option should be in the selected state.  For example:

```
<% IF list_of_sentences %>
  <% FOREACH sentence IN list_of_sentences %>
    <option value="<% sentence.value %>"<% IF sentence.is_selected %> selected="selected"<% END %> />
  <% END %>
<% END %>
```

And use the following data structure for your sentences:

```
{ value => $value, is_selected => 0|1 }
```

Comment: still fiddling around with it, but definitely seems to be on right tracks, cheers!

Comment: I am passing the structure for sentences using:
template 'main',{ sentences => ( value => $value, is_selected => 0|1 ) }
`sentences` is a hash (ref), but when I use 'sentence.value' it reads the elements like it is an array. Is there some way of saything that `sentences` is a hash? I think I've seen the `key` keyword used somewhere, but can't find any examples online.

Comment: @bladepanthera That part depends on what template engine you're using.  Do you define a template engine to use, or are you using `Dancer::Template::Simple`?  If you're not using the `set template => ` statement then you're using `Simple`.

Comment: I'm using `template toolkit` in theory although it may not be working properly as I have to use <% %> and not [% %] in my html. So may actually be using `simple`

Comment: @bladepanthera After re-reading your comment, make sure that your line reads: `template 'main',{ sentences => { value => $value, is_selected => 0 } }`.  It looks like your using `()` instead of `{}` for sentences, which would be a list.  Also, the value for `is_selected` should be either 0 or 1, as in true or false.  You would set that via your form processing logic.

Comment: I understand your logic, but I'm doing something wrong. It also messes up with my array which is `$value` as it still thinks the hash is a list. I'm going to have to play with this a bit more, but thanks for your help :)